# Can I pdfcrop a specific page out of a pdf containing several pages?

Tags: pdfcrop

Can I pdfcrop a specific page out of a pdf containing several pages, say I want page 3 from a pdf that has four pages

Comment: There is an undocumented page= option in \includegraphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you should use a two-step process:

1. Extract the page of interest.

   This can be done using [The PDF Toolkit](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/):

   ```
   pdftk in.pdf cat 3 output out.pdf
   ```

   You can also extract it using the following minimal TeX document

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pdfpages}
   \begin{document}
   \includepdf[page=3]{in}% Extract only page 3 from in.pdf
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Use [`pdfcrop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop):

   ```
   pdfcrop out.pdf
   ```

---

If the main intent is to include only page 3 of some larger, multi-page document, then you can include it via [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)

```
\includepdf[page=3]{in}
```

or via [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)

```
\includegraphics[page=3]{in}
```

Both of the above options allow you to trim the inclusion, if needed.

Comment: Yes, that's good solution. Thanks :). I also found that you can use Adobe Acrobat to extract a specific page - on the left panel of Adobe Acrobat click thumbnail tab and then right click on the page you want to extract, select extract pages from the pop up window :)

Comment: @Jiapan: Of course, if you have professional software for doing this, then that'll work too. You can also print page 3 of the PDF to PDF using [PDF Creator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator)...